# Activate C++ 11 on netbeans 7.2 mac os x

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-7

I have followed the instructions for installing C++ for netbeans 7.2 on mac os x ( http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/cpp-setup-instructions.html). But I don't seem to have access to any of the new features such as `nullptr`. Does anyone know how I can activate C++11 on my mac for netbeans?

Comment: Rapptz's reply tells you where to enter the relevant compiler options inside Netbeans. The real problem however might be a different one: which compiler are you actually using? The gcc/g++ included with Mac OS X is a 4.2 version, which is so old that you cannot expect any (or close to none) support of C++11 (see [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)). If Netbeans is using clang, the C++11 support depends on the installed version of your OS and Xcode ([link](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)). Also consider installing a current version of gcc/clang via finkproject or macports.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using GCC with Netbeans, you have to append the `-std=c++11` compilation flag.

Which according to the Googling that I've done, is accessible via `Project Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Additional Options.`